# CSS Анимация движения картинки

Tags: html, css, css-animation

Здравствуйте. Подскажите, как заставить картинку по достижению определенной точки двигаться обратно? Что я имею:

```
.blok1 {
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url('/resources/admin/back.jpg');
    -webkit-filter: blur(3px);
    -moz-filter: blur(3px);
    -o-filter: blur(3px);
    -ms-filter: blur(3px);
    filter: blur(3px);
    position:fixed;
    width:100%;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    z-index:-1;
    -webkit-animation: backgroundScroll 30s linear infinite;
    animation: backgroundScroll 30s linear infinite;
    background-size:130% 100%;
    background-position:top;
    background-attachment:fixed;
}


body{margin:0px; padding:0px;}
@-webkit-keyframes backgroundScroll {
    from {background-position: 0 0;}
    to {background-position: -400px 0;}
}

@keyframes backgroundScroll {
    from {background-position: 0 0;}
    to {background-position: -400px 0;}
}
```

Все это заставляет картинку на фоне плавно двигаться влево, пока не будет достигнут правый край картинки, в этот момент она перескочит на начало, но хотелось бы что бы она так же плавно поменяла направление и вернулась туда. Подскажите пожалуйста как реализовать.

Comment: https://html5book.ru/css3-animation/ . Почитай про свойства

Comment: @Yuri  спасибо, разобрался и открыл для себя крутой сайт :)

Comment: Не за что, тоже нравится этот сайт :)

Answer (score 3):

Так вроде

```css
.fill{
 background:#cc0;
 width:300px;
 height:300px;
 position:relative;
 margin:100px;
}
.stock{
 width:100px;
 height:100px;
 border-radius:100px;
 position:absolute;
 top:0; left:0;
 animation:pos 5s infinite ease-in-out;
 transform:rotate(360deg);
 background:linear-gradient(red,blue);
 transition:scale 5s linear;
 z-index:-10;
}

@keyframes pos{
 0%{
  top:100px;
  left:320px;
 }
 50%{
  top:100px;
  left:320px;
  transform:scale(.5);
  z-index:-10;
 }
 70%{
  left:-100px;
  top:100px;
  z-index:-10;
 }
 80%{
  z-index:10;
  left:-120px;
  top:100px;
 }
 100%{
  left:320px;
  top:100px;
  z-index:10;
  transform:scale(1.3);
 }
}
```

```html
<div class="fill"> 
   <div class="stock"></div>
</div>
```